# Rotating polygon coordinates on a map (Google Map API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geometry, polygon

I have a set of latitude and longitude coordinates in an array. When plotted as points on a Polygon in Google Maps, they form roughly an irregular oval pointing from west to east.

I would like to rotate the polygon to arbitrary degrees with a point near the far left (western) axis as the origin point.

What's important to me is that the overall distances are preserved — the total length and width of the polygon in miles should be preserved even though size of the polygon in pixels will obviously vary because of the map projection.

I've spent many hours Googling and searching on this site for an answer to this question but haven't been able to find one. Strictly speaking this is not a Google Maps issue — it's just a geometry issue related to rotating polygons on a map projection.

Here is more or less (some things dropped/renamed for simplicity) what I've been playing with so far:

```
function transpose_poly() {
//the polygon I'm transposing; these are actually in lng,lat not lat,lng
var poly = [
    [165.2467094000077,11.90511591102683],[165.1960646350092,11.8776472999036],[165.163749733589,11.84385698549516],[165.1260503052001,11.79105209544025],[165.1174590975139,11.73721064669002],[165.1239723221977,11.68443896599666],[165.1455712453083,11.62322111902237],[165.1628352566873,11.60212814234246],[165.2801792409835,11.57112282455308],[165.3469838984795,11.55321856612457],[165.4267372080734,11.49929306693537],[165.565122175408,11.43334434041074],[165.7036021721537,11.37198352732909],[165.7982543390455,11.32757670668951],[165.942446703552,11.2660302522167],[166.0435044916007,11.23207374453692],[166.1628753311194,11.19161490039798],[166.3468035041342,11.13537294275959],[166.432786256031,11.11077339082378],[166.6460225244011,11.09603091173615],[166.9054486129032,11.10353634871533],[167.0953310801652,11.11920326808891],[167.2738338244123,11.14546202299651],[167.5299835821322,11.20017441185735],[167.7587090824888,11.25007287877568],[168.0532186132958,11.32987818697488],[168.3030699093596,11.40339603540862],[168.592055474493,11.49329084618948],[168.8894586866613,11.59767488596071],[169.1097084341002,11.70426500697907],[169.3388671138959,11.8464629880637],[169.47335151263,11.96284699062962],[169.4987805640997,12.00051052731504],[169.5113979458664,12.04997756596092],[169.496674063518,12.07975001861134],[169.4439862794831,12.10473302818016],[169.3792705121883,12.11718325976015],[169.2053586392944,12.12366910168141],[169.0210976722354,12.12171866909852],[168.7390558752391,12.08703266811138],[168.4733370821476,12.04764814638675],[168.1055698159765,12.00021651042535],[167.8745488025422,11.97152786285725],[167.5955303201492,11.94724207538445],[167.1571321566584,11.94152529858467],[166.8673995936747,11.95771709621411],[166.6698153277294,11.98911065050636],[166.4432968316392,12.03361885637251],[166.2604579582592,12.0693923391982],[166.0834945953367,12.09610600014998],[165.9206278637858,12.10688793842689],[165.7421018997999,12.1070118835482],[165.6244752224984,12.09489163127243],[165.4939687494391,12.0642833194958],[165.4055155587918,12.02521842289156],[165.3386147079753,11.97769336095395],[165.278157772496,11.92168821285675],[165.2467094000077,11.90511591102683],
    ];

    var pos = marker.getPosition(); //where it transposes it to
    var marker_lat = pos.lat(); 
    var marker_lng = pos.lng();
    var angle = document.getElementById("poly_angle").value; //rotational angle

    var original_lat = 11.697222; //the original lat/lng of the polygon coordinates above
    var original_lng = 165.27194399999996; //used to move the general polygon to a new set of coords as an offset

    var new_poly = []; //the transformed polygon

//iterate over polygon array, create new array of Google Maps LatLng objects that are transposed and rotated
    for(var i=0; i<poly.length; i++) {
        new_poly.push( rotateLatLng( (poly[i][1]-original_lat)+marker_lat,(poly[i][0].lng()-original_lng)+marker_lng,angle));

    }

    // plot the polygon on the map
    poly_obj = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: poly_new,
        strokeColor: "#ff763b",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#ff763b",
        fillOpacity: 0.25,
        map: map,
        visible: true
    });

}

//this rotating function is cobbled together from code I found... it doesn't really work. It somewhat rotates it but distorts it terribly and gives really bizarre results
function rotateLatLng (pointLat,pointLng,angle) {
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    var theX = pointLat;
    var theY = pointLng;
    var rotationTheta = angle;
    var rotationThetaRad = rotationTheta*(Math.PI/180);
    var rotationOriginX = pos.lat();
    var rotationOriginY = pos.lng();

    var newX;
    var newY;

    if (rotationOriginX == 0 && rotationOriginY == 0) {
        newX = theX * Math.cos(rotationThetaRad) - Math.sin(rotationThetaRad) * theY;
        newY = theX * Math.sin(rotationThetaRad) + Math.cos(rotationThetaRad) * theY;
    } else {
        newX = (theX - rotationOriginX) * Math.cos(rotationThetaRad) - (theY - rotationOriginY) * Math.sin(rotationTheta) + rotationOriginX;
        newY = (theX - rotationOriginX) * Math.sin(rotationThetaRad) + (theY - rotationOriginY) * Math.cos(rotationTheta) + rotationOriginY;
    }


  return new google.maps.LatLng(newX,newY);
}
```

I don't think the above is necessarily the right way to do it at all. Any pointers would be helpful.

**A much more simplified version** of this problem would be to say that if I had an origin point of lat1,lng1, and another target point of lat2,lng2, how do I calculate lat3,lng3 which is defined as being the same distance between lat1,lng1 and lat2,lng2 but at an arbitrary angle? Because if I knew how to do that, applying that to the entire polygon should be a snap.